# How I change a value of a sepecific attribute in all object of LIST

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Can i update one `attribute` in all object in a `LIST` with a same value when the `LIST` is loaded, without a `loop`?`

```
List<E>myList= new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<E>>map;
myList.add(object);// object{attr1,attr2,attr3}
myList.size();//40
//traitement 
map.put(key,myList);

//444+23=[object[attr1=value1, attr2= null, attr3=value3] , object[attr1=value4, attr2= null, attr3=value5]]

map.get(key).set(myList.attr2,value6);
 //result
 //444+23=[object[attr1=value1, attr2= value6, attr3=value3] , object[attr1=value4, attr2= value6, attr3=value5]]
```

Comment: Would you give us an example?

Comment: Sounds like an interview question that was expecting you to know about [Iterable.forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

Comment: By writing some code. What _specifically_ prevents you from writing it?

Comment: i read data form a excel file, and i put some data it depends an other data from file. thakns guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `ArrayList` you can use `ArrayList#set`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-

edit: If you're talking about mutating an attribute on every object in the list, then no, you can't do it without some kind of traversal over the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant you have to traverse the entire list to do that